# How to tell GNU MAKE to treat .po files like .h files?

Tags: c, makefile

I have a .c file that is dependent on a generated include file named control.po but when it is included in the dependencies, make thinks it needs to build it.

`` make[1]: *** No rule to make target `control.po', needed by `proccmd.o'.  Stop. ``

```
proccmd.o:  ddemsgid.do ddelen.do control.po tprecs.ro tlktp.h comtrac.h basmsg.fo \
        tiop.h
```

If I copy control.po to control.fo and change the dependency control.po, it compiles.

I have tried changing .SUFFIXES
this way

```
.SUFFIXES:
.SUFFIXES: .c .o .h .po
```

and this

```
.SUFFIXES:
.SUFFIXES: .c .o .h
```

with the same result.

I am ASSUMING there is some implied rule about .po files.

I am converting a large project from a proprietary build to gnu make, so I cannot easily change the file extensions of the generated files.

Comment: You should **read the [documentation of GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html)**, since you need to add your own rules, and be aware of builtin rules (run `make -p`). You could consider using [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) to debug your `Makefile`

Comment: Without some [MCVE] your question is off-topic here.

Comment: BTW, for a large project, I would consider migrating to [ninja](http://ninja-build.org/) instead of the old GNU `make` (since `ninja` is *designed* for huge project builds)

Comment: Well. the `control.po` either needs to be there. Or make needs to know how to build / generate it. By either having an explicit rule, or pattern rule telling it how to. However, the question does not seem to make that immediately clear what the mechanics of generating the file should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am ASSUMING there is some implied rule about .po files.

Wrong assumption. The builtin rules are obtained with `make -p` and they don't mention `.po`

---

As I told in comments:

- when building a large project, [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/) is more suitable (it runs by default in parallel, like `make -j` and it runs faster). If you are migrating from a proprietary build system, it probably would be better. You'll need to write or find your `build.ninja` generator (e.g. with your Python script generating it, with [meson](https://mesonbuild.com/), etc...).
- If you stay with GNU `make`, you should add your own recipes and rules for your `.po` suffix (assuming that your `foo.po` is generated from some `foo.src`). So **read the [documentation of GNU `make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html)** and you may want some [rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Rules.html#Rules) like

  ```
  %.po: %.src
     # how to build a .po from some .src fle
  ```
- You could find useful to use [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) with `-x` for debugging your `Makefile`

Comment: As posted .. bad assumption, I failed to add a vpath

Answer (score -1):

the generated include files are in a different directory and I failed to add an vpath entry for .po files..

VPATH_INCLUDE_LIST  = ../include:../../include:../../../include:../../../../include

vpath %h $(VPATH_INCLUDE_LIST)
vpath %.do $(VPATH_INCLUDE_LIST)
vpath %.fo $(VPATH_INCLUDE_LIST)
vpath %.to $(VPATH_INCLUDE_LIST)
vpath %.ro $(VPATH_INCLUDE_LIST)
vpath %.go $(VPATH_INCLUDE_LIST)
vpath %.po $(VPATH_INCLUDE_LIST)